# DL380 G7 w/ SmartArray P410i - Disk "Bad Target Count"

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a DL380 G7 with 8 x 600GB 10K RPM SAS disks in it. I'm just running some diagnostics on it before putting it in production. Thus far, no errors had popped up until I ran the HP SmartStart CD (latest version v8.70 B).

The error is this:

```
An unexpected exception occurred while performing an operation.

Exception message: CISS_StatusHanlder::evalulate:commandStatus = 4 (INVALID) 

Device: Hard Drive 8, Storage Controller in Slot 0
Property Name: Bad Target Count
```

So obviously I thought drive 8 was faulty. I swapped drives 8 & 1, expecting the error to follow the drive. But, it didn't. I still get the same error above. I then installed a replacement backplane (I had spares). The error STILL persists. I have ensured all firmwares and ROMs on this server are at their latest versions.

Also I should clarify that the HP diagnostics do NOT show any hardware in the server (including the disks/RAID controller) as faulty. They all pass the test. 
[image]

The above error is seen in the Log > Error Log screen of the HP Insight Diagnostics which I happened across.
[image: Error]

Any ideas on how I can diagnose what the issue with this server is?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with running diagnostics preemptively. There's also no need to use the HP Insight Diagnostics to check on the disk array. The Array Configuration Utility (or Smart Storage Administrator tool) handles that just fine. That's what I'd trust.

Just install the server as normal and deal with any issues using normal monitoring features.

The HP SmartStart CD is deprecated. Please use the current [HP Service Pack for ProLiant DVD](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx) for provisioning, firmware and diagnostics.